# mIRC parsing for a name

Tags: parsing, scripting, mirc

So I've been getting a bothersome someone who keeps using my nickname. What I want to be able to do is perform the following command every time someone with exactly my nickname (let's say UserName) joins the channel I currently reside in:

/msg NickServ ghost UserName n0ideaHwatPassIs?

n0ideaHwatPassIs? is a sample password for our sample registered user of UserName

This sort of script would have to be able to check (in more or less real-time) if a separate user changed his/her nick to said UserName as well. If someone would be so kind as to help me with my dilemma by either pointing me to the proper documentation or working out such a script (no idea if this is as cut-and-dry as I imagined it would be at first) for me?

Comment: not sure if this wouldn't belong on https://superuser.com instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I'll try my luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a on notify event

but first, you have to put that nickname on notify list

type

```
/notify nickname
```

then use this script, press alt+r click on file, then new and put this script in there

```
on *:notify:{
if ($nick != $me) && ($nick == Nickyouwanthere) {
  msg NickServ ghost UserName n0ideaHwatPassIs
}
```

Comment: Never mind, I chose your code with just the second condition and it works perfectly fine now... Thank you very much for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

`every time someone with exactly my nickname (let's say UserName) joins the channel I currently reside in`

This can't happen on IRC.  (Except in exceptional circumstances like netsplits, but is immediately resolved then (by dropping one or both parties))

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. I meant I stay on an alternate nick while "away" in the channel i.e. UserName|away. The trouble is that I need to get rid of whoever the jokester thinks he/she is when they fake my name.

Comment: It's a process through which I at times need to be able to keep my nick clear from other people using it while at the same time not using it myself. Using it at all except for my predetermined specific intervals brings chaos upon my nick. But that's a backstory relating to the type of channel I'm a part of and not quite pertinent to the problem at hand.